# Blocking and non-blocking WNOHANG

Tags: c

I have a section in my main code where I am waiting on a process to finish executing before calling a block of code, but there is another loop I want to run during the time the main code is waiting as indicated below.

```
int status;
if (waitpid(pid, &status, WNOHANG) == 0)
{
    while (1)
    {
        // code whilst waiting goes here
    }
}

if (WEXITSTATUS(status) > ERROR) 
{
    // code to run after process has exited
}
```

Structured like this however, the while loop will continue forever with no end, and if I have no loop after `WNOHANG` then the code in `WEXITSTATUS` will execute immediately with no waiting at all.

I have looked into something like waiting for a `SIGCHLD` signal, but the code in the `WEXITSTATUS` block requires several arguments which I cannot easily pass on through a signal handler. I have also looked into opening a new process for the loop code block before waiting, but as I am using a linked list it is hard to return that list back to the parent process to do something with.

If what I am intending is not clear let me know and I will try to clarify. I am mostly wondering if there is any possibility to achieve what I specify in the code above; running some code whilst waiting before running the rest of the code. Thank you.

Comment: Why can't you just put the `waitpid` inside the `while` loop and break from the loop when it tells you the child has exited?

Comment: @kaylum Thank you for the suggestion. I ended up using `while (waitpid(pid, &status, WNOHANG) == 0)` instead of `while (1)` and it seems to work as intended, but I will run some more tests first.